# SLI don't works adequately

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I installed two video cards, plugged in the SLI bridge, turned on the SLI via sudo `nvidia-xconfig -sli = afr`, and found a black screen on restart. I have also tried similar commands like `nvidia-xconfig -sli = on` and others, but the result is the same.
This happens with two identical gtx 580s for 3gb and a platform on fx 8300, ubuntu 20.04. I am not very versed in ubuntu and am writing here.
There were similar articles here but none of them contained a specific solution to the problem.

Comment: What were the results of those commands. Have you installed the Nvidia drivers for starters?

Comment: I tried all the drivers (open, 340th and 390th) and none of them worked. The terminal responded to the command like this:
"Using X configuration file:" /etc/X11/xorg.conf ".
Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' "

Comment: It's it's a UEFI system don't forget to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: it is doesn't work regardless of uefi or not

Answer (score -1):

Use either `--sli=SLI` or `--no-sli` to respectively enable or disable SLI.  **Valid values for SLI are 'Off' and 'Mosaic'.**

Also you have to use double prefix before:

```
nvidia-xconfig --sli=Mosaic
```

instead of

```
nvidia-xconfig -sli=...
```